# ASP.NET MVC MembershipService Email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, membership-provider

I have been working on an MVC project and I everything works at the moment except I can't force the user to confirm the email address before I active the user's account.

I am using the built-in MembershipService/MembershipProvider that came with MVC. I was thinking of sending a normal email using an SmtpClient and MailMessage and then making a viewpage to confirm the account by changing the IsApproved value inside an ActionResult.

Is there a better way of doing it or maybe even a built in MembershipService function for doing such a job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Membership services provided by the framework don't support this directly.
Your backup plan sounds OK though. This [link](http://weblogs.manas.com.ar/smedina/?p=5) may help too.

Comment: Thank You for your response. The link you provided was very useful and I have made a couple of small changes to my code based on the link you provided. Thanks Again!